# Toyota Navigation System Connector doesn't fit Pioneer receiver

Tags: toyota, audio, wiring, camry, entertainment-system

I'm trying to replace my car stereo in my 2006 Toyota Camry XLE with navigation system.

I had the default navigation system Denso DW468100-0150 and wanted CarPlay and Bluetooth, so I bought the [Pioneer AVH4200NEX 2-DIN Receiver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01D6HPMZQ)

I followed the Cruchfield and Amazon "it fits" guides for my vehicle, but the *Metra 70-1761 Radio Wiring Harness For Toyota 87-Up Power 4 Speaker* doesn't fit into my 20 pin connector shown below. Additionally, I can't figure out my pin colors or how to connect things.

First, I had

[This post](http://www.castulucci.com/projects/carpc/oemnaviconnectors/) gets close and explains a lot, but the colors don't match.

[image: Pins]

Here is what I purchased from Amazon that isn't working.

[image: Amazon purchase]

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the pioneer comes with a female connector, you could just hard wire the pioneer harness to the Toyota harness, but you need to match up what the Toyota harness wires go to with what the pioneer controls, and this is just done via pioneer manual and Toyota manual

Comment: I have the Toyota Entertainment System Manual -- but it is just a user manual with no Pin-outs. I can get all the data needed on the Pioneer. I could always cut and connect the wires if I can determine their purpose.

Comment: Search 2006 Toyota Camry xle wiring harness diagram, goto images and click on the first one in google. This looks like what you need, but keep searching incase I’m wrong!

Comment: @sjfklsdafjks You're much better off linking the result(s) you find, as Google doesn't serve the same results to everyone.